# Spring 3.0.5 - Adding @ModelAttribute to handler method signature results in JsonMappingException

Tags: json, spring-mvc, automapping, jackson, modelattribute

I'm not sure whether this is a misconfiguration on my part, a misunderstanding of what can be accomplished via `@ModelAttribute` and automatic JSON content conversion, or a bug in either Spring or Jackson. If it turns out to be the latter, of course, I'll file an issue with the appropriate folks.

I've encountered a problem with adding a `@ModelAttribute` to a controller's handler method. The intent of the method is to expose a bean that's been populated from a form or previous submission, but I can reproduce the issue without actually submitting data into the bean.

I'm using the Spring mvc-showcase sample. It's currently using Spring 3.1, but I first encountered, and am able to reproduce, this issue on my 3.0.5 setup. The mvc-showcase sample uses a pretty standard servlet-context.xml:

### servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService">
        <argument-resolvers>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.samples.mvc.data.custom.CustomArgumentResolver"/>
        </argument-resolvers>
    </annotation-driven>

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources/ directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Imports user-defined @Controller beans that process client requests -->
    <beans:import resource="controllers.xml" />

    <!-- Only needed because we install custom converters to support the examples in the org.springframewok.samples.mvc.convert package -->
    <beans:bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.samples.mvc.convert.CustomConversionServiceFactoryBean" />

    <!-- Only needed because we require fileupload in the org.springframework.samples.mvc.fileupload package -->
    <beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

</beans:beans>
```

---

The `controllers.xml` referenced in the file simply sets up the relevant component-scan and view-controller for the root path. The relevant snippet is below.

### controllers.xml

```
<!-- Maps '/' requests to the 'home' view -->
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="home"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.samples.mvc" />
```

---

The test bean which I am attempting to deliver is a dead-simple POJO.

### TestBean.java

```
package org.springframework.samples.mvc.test;

public class TestBean {
    private String testField = "test@example.com";

    public String getTestField() {
        return testField;
    }

    public void setTestField(String testField) {
        this.testField = testField;
    }

}
```

---

And finally, the controller, which is also simple.

### TestController.java

```
package org.springframework.samples.mvc.test;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("test/*")
public class TestController {

    @ModelAttribute("testBean")
    public TestBean getTestBean() {
        return new TestBean();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "beanOnly", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    TestBean testBean(@ModelAttribute("testBean") TestBean bean) {
        return bean;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "withoutModel", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    Model testWithoutModel(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("result", "success");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "withModel", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    Model testWithModel(Model model, @ModelAttribute("testBean") TestBean bean) {
        bean.setTestField("This is the new value of testField");
        model.addAttribute("result", "success");
        return model;
    }

}
```

---

If I call the controller via the mapped path `/mvc-showcase/test/beanOnly`, I get a JSON representation of the bean, as expected. Calling the `withoutModel` handler delivers a JSON representation of the Spring `Model` object associated with the call. It includes the implicit `@ModelAttribute` from the initial declaration in the return value, but the bean is unavailable to the method. If I wish to process the results of a form submission, for example, and return a JSON response message, then I need that attribute.

The last method adds the `@ModelAttribute`, and this is where the trouble comes up. Calling `/mvc-showcase/test/withModel` causes an exception.

In my 3.0.5 installation, I get a JsonMappingException caused by a lack of serializer for FormattingConversionService. In the 3.1.0 sample, the exception is caused by lack of serializer for DefaultConversionService. I'll include the 3.1 exception here; it seems to have the same root cause, even if the path is a bit different.

### 3.1 org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.format.support.DefaultFormattingConversionService and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: org.springframework.validation.support.BindingAwareModelMap["org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.testBean"]->org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult["propertyAccessor"]->org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl["conversionService"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider$1.failForEmpty(StdSerializerProvider.java:89)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider$1.serialize(StdSerializerProvider.java:62)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serializeFields(BeanSerializer.java:175)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:147)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serializeFields(BeanSerializer.java:175)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:147)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:207)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:140)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:22)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:242)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1030)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:153)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:181)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.support.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.support.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:101)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.support.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMethodAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMethodAdapter.java:505)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMethodAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerMethodAdapter.java:468)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at 
...
```

So, is there some configuration I am missing that should allow the Jackson converter to properly handle a response derived from a handler with `@ModelAttribute` in the method signature? If not, any thoughts as to whether this is more likely a Spring bug or a Jackson bug? I'm leaning toward Spring, at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a Spring config problem, when serializing to JSON the `DefaultFormattingConversionService` is empty and Jackson (by default) will throw an exception if a bean is empty see `FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS` in the [features documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeaturesSerialization). But I am not clear why the bean is empty.

It **should** work if you set `FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS` to false, but still doesn't really explain why it is happening in the first place.

`DefaultFormattingConversionService` is new to 3.1 - it extends the FormattingConversionService which explains the different exceptions between 3.0.5 and 3.1.

I do not think it is a Jackson problem, although a new version of Jackson ([1.8.0](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.8.0/release-notes/VERSION)) was [released](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload) only 3 days ago so you could try that also.

I will try to reproduce this locally.

Comment: That's what I'm leaning toward as well--I suspect there's either a bug in the interaction, or some configuration that I'm missing somewhere in the chain. I've opened an issue on spring; we'll see if that has any useful results https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8272

Comment: A followup: I disabled the `FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS` feature, and am now seeing a circular reference error. I'll keep poking at it, but for now, I'm probably going to lean toward using a custom bean instead of returning a `Model` based return value in those methods where I require a `@ModelAttribute` to be passed to the handler.

Comment: Final word: See the comments in the Spring issue for an explanation: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8272 . Essentially, the model is automatically instrumented with BindingResults references that cause the circular reference error. The correct paradigm is to do what I eventually did: Expose the required data and bindingResults values in an object of our own making. I'd sure like to see that built into Spring, but well, that's why it's open-source, I guess. :)

Comment: @Palpatim thanks for posting the follow up. I guess most of the applications I have written use custom serializers to either cater for cyclical references or exposing a streamlined view of the model.